# GUI: прозрачное изображение

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения, gui, tkinter

Делаю по фану фиговинку на `tkinter`, необходимо вставить в канвас-холст изображение с прозрачным фоном. Т.к python 3 версии я не могу юзать `PIL`, а стандартными либами открыть `.png` не получается. Подскажите, как мне открыть изображение с прозрачными элементами?

Может как-нибудь через альфа канал?

Comment: ставьте pillow

Comment: Кстати, есть приватные порты PIL на Python3. См. [сюда][1]  

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896286/image-library-for-python-3

Comment: я когда питон учил, в книге было сказано gimp скачать, через него я делал

Answer (score 2):

Порт `PIL` для `python3`:

```
pip install pillow
```

Пример:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open(image_file)
```